# how to configure wifi power management in debian jessie

Tags: wireless-networking, debian, power-management

I have a plain Debian Jessie installation on my Thinkpad x230. Everything works smooth but I noticed that wifi powermanagement is set to 'off'. I can activate power management manually but after reboot the it is off again. I found one hint on the net that suggested to put a script in /etc/pm/power.d that activates wifi powermanagenment via iwconfig. This did not help something else is overriding it or the script is not even called. :-/

Is there any way how the handling of wifi powermanagement is done properly (I guess this might be some systemd magic)?

Best Regards,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was not systemd but Gnome's NetworkManager. I used the [hints on this site](http://patrick.vande-walle.eu/software/kubuntu/wlan-powersave-mode-in-ubuntu-and-performance/) to create a small script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d that switches on power management when the interface comes up.